# How do I implement the Textbox AppendText property in accordance with MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox

I am trying to make a live data monitoring application. But I have performance issues. I've included a screenshot of the design below for ease of explanation.

I want to show data from serial or ethernet in a textbox in formats like "Hexadecimal", "ASCII", "Decimal", "Binary".

I'm trying to do it in a MVVM-friendly way. I have byte[] variable in ViewModel. I add the incoming data to this variable. I show the byte format in the desired format with Converter in Xaml. Functionally it works but is slow.

ViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private byte[] _data;

    public byte[] Data
    {
        get => _data;
        set => SetProperty(ref _data, value);
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Data = new byte[] { };
    }

    private void DataClearClick(object param)
    {
        Array.Clear(Data, 0, Data.Length);
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
            <syncfusion:TabItemExt Header="ASCII">
            <syncfusion:SfTextBoxExt Margin="10"
                                     Text="{Binding Data, Converter={StaticResource ByteToASCIIConverter}}"  
                                     TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                     AcceptsReturn="True"
                                     MaxLines="70"/>
        </syncfusion:TabItemExt>
```

ASCII Converter

```
        private string StringToAscii(byte[] array)
    {
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            str = str + asciiCharacter[array[i]];
        }

        return str;
    }

    string[] asciiCharacter = new string[] { "<NULL>", "<SOH>", "<STX>", "<ETX>", "<EOT>", "<ENQ>", "<ACK>", "<BEL>",
                                             "<BS>", "<HT>", "<LF>", "<VT>", "<FF>", "<CR>", "<SO>", "<SI>",
                                             "<DLE>", "<DC1>", "<DC2>", "<DC3>", "<DC4>", "<NAK>", "<SYN>", "<ETB>",
                                             "<CAN>", "<EM>", "<SUB>", "<ESC>", "<FS>", "<GS>", "<RS>", "<US>",
                                             "<SP>","!", "\"\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'",
                                             "(",")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/",
                                             "0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                                             "8","9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?",
                                             "@","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
                                             "H","I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
                                             "P","Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W",
                                             "X","Y", "Z", "[", "\"\"", "]", "^", "_",
                                             "`","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
                                             "h","i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
                                             "p","q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w",
                                             "x","y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~", "<DEL>",
                                             "€", " ", "‚", "ƒ", "„", "…", "†", "‡",
                                             "ˆ", "‰", "Š", "‹", "Œ", " ", "Ž", " ",
                                             " ", "‘", "’", "“", "”", "•", "–", "—",
                                             "˜", "™", "š", "›", "œ", " ", "ž", "Ÿ",
                                             " ", "¡", "¢", "£", "¤", "¥", "¦", "§",
                                             "¨", "©", "ª", "«", "¬", " ", "®", "¯",
                                             "°", "±", "²", "³", "´", "µ", "¶", "·",
                                             "¸", "¹", "º", "»", "¼", "½", "¾", "¿",
                                             "À", "Á", "Â", "Ã", "Ä", "Å", "Æ", "Ç",
                                             "È", "É", "Ê", "Ë", "Ì", "Í", "Î", "Ï",
                                             "Ð", "Ñ", "Ò", "Ó", "Ô", "Õ", "Ö", "×",
                                             "Ø", "Ù", "Ú", "Û", "Ü", "Ý", "Þ", "ß",
                                             "à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä", "å", "æ", "ç",
                                             "è", "é", "ê", "ë", "ì", "í", "î", "ï",
                                             "ð", "ñ", "ò", "ó", "ô", "õ", "ö", "÷",
                                             "ø", "ù", "ú", "û", "ü", "ý", "þ", "ÿ",};

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return StringToAscii((byte[])value);
        }
```

Similar to above, I have binary, decimal and hexadecimal converters. I didn't want to add every single one of them as it would be a lot of code. I know that using a converter is inefficient. I'm not sure how to approach.

In addition, I moved away from MVVM and added the AppendText property with code-behind. This provided a significant performance boost. Still not quite enough. Setting the MaxLine property gave me an increase in performance. I found a few things about UI virtualization. I couldn't figure out how to implement it for textbox.

**How can I improve performance with similar approaches? How can I implement AppendText in MVVM?**

If I am wrong, please guide me.

Performance level expectations; The fact that it can display the incoming data in 100 ms in 4 separate textboxes.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString` method?

Comment: The Encoding.ASCII method returns only 0-128 bytes of data.

Comment: I misunderstood that there are only ASCII charactors and you want to replace control codes.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should use `StringBuilder` for performance-sensitive concatenation. Thus your StringToAscii method can be modified as follows.

```cs
private string StringToAscii(byte[] array)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in array)
    {
        switch (b)
        {
            case <= 32 or 34 or 92 or >= 127:
                buffer.Append(asciiCharacter[b]);
                break;
            default:
                buffer.Append((char)b);
                break;
        };
    }
    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem affecting performance. Feeding all the data to the converter each time seriously reduces performance. Can you show me the way to properly implement the AppendText method in MVVM?

Comment: It is commonly known that string concatenation by '+' causes a huge performance  degradation.

Comment: I applied the change. But there wasn't a huge performance increase. I probably have a general approach error.